# How do I use Session_Start in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

It's quite weird, I thought that simply adding this code in the `Global.asax.cs` would be enough:

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // your code here, it will be executed upon session start
}
```

But the method isn't called... How do I let ASP.NET call a the `Session_Start` method when the session starts?

I can't figure how to catch the event of a session creation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that is enough ... when you have enabled sessions:

```
<system.web>
  <sessionState cookieName="auth" mode="InProc" timeout="480"/>
</system.web>
```